# Is it possible that dark energy could be non-uniformly distributed?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Is it even possible that dark energy could be non-uniformly distributed? If it were the case at some points where creation is faster would some objects like for example stars move apart with a rate dependent of the location where dark energy is more intense or where is weaker? Can large voids in the universe be explained in another way?

Comment: I don't think so. It can't if it's [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant). The main alternative is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintessence_(physics)), but I can only find discussion of that varying across time, not space (working in conformal coordinates).

Comment: If you are talking about scale dependent cosmological constant, you might find this interesting: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.10831v2

Comment: There might be no dark matter. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_qJptwikRc) mentions about a study on it.